# CSS rotating cube doesn't work after translateZ on cube

Tags: jquery, html, css, 3d, transform

In this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PaulvdDool/grwnT/1/) I've created a 100% width cube that rotates horizontally when pressing a button. The cube is moved forward however as if scaled up so I added a `translateZ` function to it. This has to be added with jQuery because of the dynamic size of the cube. This is my jQuery:

```
var windowWidth = ($(window).width() / 2);
$('div#cube').css({
    'transform': 'translateZ(-' + windowWidth + 'px)',
    '-webkit-transform': 'translateZ(-' + windowWidth + 'px)',
    '-moz-transform': 'translateZ(-' + windowWidth + 'px)'
});
```

But this seems to prevent the cube from rotating and I don't know why. When I add the translateZ in CSS the cube is able to rotate.

```
#cube {
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    transform: translateZ(-100px);
    -webkit-transform: translateZ(-100px);
    -moz-transform: translateZ(-100px);
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    transition: transform 1s;
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 1s;
    -moz-transition: -moz-transform 1s;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Is there an error in my code? Did I approach it wrong? Or is what I'm trying to do, impossible?

Comment: I have updated with a version that doesn't cause the css to grow, but I think that you get the idea anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the by setting `css` you are setting the style and this takes precedence over the class. You will need to accumulate the transforms on the css, by applying it each time rather than using classes. A simple way to do this is shown in **[this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/grwnT/2/)**.

Essentially, there is a method:

```
function doTransform($elem, theTransform)
{
    $elem.css('transform', $elem.css('transform') + ' ' + theTransform )
    $elem.css('-webkit-transform:', $elem.css('transform') + ' ' + theTransform )
    $elem.css('-moz-transform', $elem.css('transform') + ' ' + theTransform )    
}
```

and a which is called on the click as follows:

```
doTransform($('#cube'),'rotateY(-90deg)');
```

**Update**

Now that is not ideal, because the css will keep growing, so a better way would be to set the translation in doTransform as well, see this **[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/grwnT/3/)**.

```
function doTransform($elem, theTransform)
{    
    var windowWidth = ($(window).width() / 2);
    var theTranslation = 'translateZ(-' + windowWidth + 'px)';    
    $elem.css('transform',  theTranslation + ' ' + theTransform )
    $elem.css('-webkit-transform:', theTranslation + ' ' + theTransform )
    $elem.css('-moz-transform', theTranslation + ' ' + theTransform )    
}
```

and then call as:

```
doTransform($('#cube'),'rotateY(-' + (90 * ctr).toString() + 'deg)');
```